# Why does backward recursion execute faster than forward recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I made an algorithm in Python for counting the number of ways of getting an amount of money with different coin denominations:

```
@measure
def countChange(n, coin_list):
    maxIndex = len(coin_list)
    def count(n, current_index):        
        if n>0 and maxIndex>current_index:
            c = 0
            current = coin_list[current_index]
            max_coeff = int(n/current)      
            for coeff in range(max_coeff+1):
                c+=count(n-coeff*current, current_index+1)
        elif n==0: return 1
        else: return 0
        return c
    return count(n, 0)
```

My algorithm uses an index to get a coin denomination and, as you can see, my index is increasing in each stack frame I get in. I realized that the algorithm could be written in this way also:

```
@measure
def countChange2(n, coin_list):
    maxIndex = len(coin_list)
    def count(n, current_index):        
        if n>0 and 0<=current_index:
            c = 0
            current = coin_list[current_index]
            max_coeff = int(n/current)      
            for coeff in range(max_coeff+1):
                c+=count(n-coeff*current, current_index-1)
        elif n==0: return 1
        else: return 0
        return c
    return count(n, maxIndex-1)
```

This time, the index is decreasing each stack frame I get in. I compared the execution time of the functions and I got a very noteworthy difference:

```
print(countChange(30, range(1, 31)))
print(countChange2(30, range(1, 31)))

>> Call to countChange took 0.9956174254208345 secods.
>> Call to countChange2 took 0.037631815734429974 secods.
```

Why is there a great difference in the execution times of the algorithms if I'm not even caching the results? Why does the increasing order of the index affect this execution time?

Comment: yes ... this is how dynamic programming works (this is an example of dynamic programming, you start at the goal state, and work backwards allowing you to skip calculations that would result in an invalid solution)... however if you start at the initial state it takes an exaustive search and does not know an answer is invalid until after calculating it

Comment: @rfrm where does `@measure` comes from?

Comment: its just a timing decorator Im sure @JanVlcinsky

Comment: @JoranBeasley This I understood, but do I have to define it or it is already somewhere prepared?

Comment: just comment it out ... and use timeit or something if you are trying to compare ...

Comment: {@measure} is only for timing as @JoranBeasley said. The question raises, because I'm NOT using any caching, any Dynamic Programming, in fact this is the previous step to make an Dynamic Programing algorithm, to express it in a recursive way.

Comment: when you start in the goal state and recusively work to the start state that is dynamic programing ... Im not sure where you are getting this information about requiring memory(caching) for dynamic programing..

Comment: "The dynamic programming approach seeks to solve each subproblem only once, thus reducing the number of computations: once the solution to a given subproblem has been computed, it is stored or "memo-ized": the next time the same solution is needed, it is simply looked up. " http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: working forward you examine all posibilities , working backwards you can eliminate invalid paths without exploring them.  this is indeed a dynamic programing solution (you are only calculating each subproblem once ... so why would you memoize it?) going forwards however you must exaustivly explore your search space ...

Comment: you can verify this behavior by putting a counter in the count function that is incremented each time count is called and print it at the end

Comment: The number of calls is dependent on the order of input. You can get the minimum number by sorting the list in descending order in `countChange`. `coin_list.sort(reverse = True)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Starting at the "goal state" and working back to the "start state" doesn't automatically make an algorithm "dynamic". Suppose I have a maze with exactly two doors, A and B. You're telling me that if I label A "enter" and B "exit", and you start at B, then you are doing some kind of "dynamic programming" maze solving? What if I switch the labels so that A reads "exit" and B reads "enter". Have I suddenly made your maze solver **not** dynamic anymore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with dynamic programming, as I understand it.  Just reversing the indices shouldn't make something "dynamic".

What's happening is that the algorithm is **input sensitive**.  Try feeding the input in reversed order.  For example,

```
print(countChange(30, list(reversed(range(1, 31)))))
print(countChange2(30, list(reversed(range(1, 31)))))
```

Just as some sorting algorithms are extremely fast with already sorted data and very slow with reversed data, you've got that kind of algorithm here.

In the case where the input is increasing, `countChange` needs a lot more iterations to arrive at its final answer, and thus seems a lot slower.  However, when the input is decreasing, the performance characteristics are reversed.

Comment: it does though(make it a dynamic programming solution) with this problem specifically, since reversing it allows you to not even explore invalid path.  it also ensures that you only calculate each subproblem once ... (+1 all the same, since yes the reason it is slower is it calls more times ...)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I think you really have misunderstood dynamic programming. Either that or you didn't take the time to examine the properties of this problem. See my edit.

Comment: your right .... im still not sure... I thought I understood dynamic programming, now im doubting myself (also I didnt really examine the algorithm OP was using... it looks like lots of stuff is recalculated ... all over the place, regardless of order) ...

Answer (score 8):

thre number combinations are not huge

**the reason is that going forward you have to explore every possibility, however when you go backwards you can eliminate large chunks of invalid solutions without having to actually calculate them**

**going forward you call count 500k times**

**going backwards your code only makes 30k calls to count ...**

you can make both of these faster by memoizing the calls , (or changing your algorithm to not make duplicate calls)

Comment: Dynamic programming needs of a mean of saving previous results, as you can see, I'm NOT saving nothing.

Comment: no it doesnt it typically is recursively called(although nothing forces that its just the most intuitive way) ... just like you are doing ... this is  dynamic programing and this is also why starting in start state is much slower than starting in your goal state ... (in fact the tutorial I wrote is this exact same problem statement)

Comment: "Reversing it allows you to not even explore invalid path" @Joran this makes sense, Thank you.

Comment: I figured bolding parts of my answer would help :P people were getting too hung up on semantics :P (me too ... maybe Im wrong and this isnt actually dynamic programming... but Im pretty sure :P)

Comment: This is not dynamic programming. Dynamic programming is fundamentally about dividing a problem into overlapping subproblems and reusing the results of subproblem computations. Nothing is reused here; in fact, `count` is called repeatedly with the same arguments in both versions. John Y's answer is significantly more accurate.

Comment: Your dynamic programming tutorial isn't even using dynamic programming. What you have in your tutorial is the non-dynamic recursive approach; it needs to be memoized to make it dynamic.

Comment: there I got rid of the parts about dynamic programing ... that said I still say this is dynamic programming, and that memoization is not a requirement of dynamic programing, however it is often used...

Comment: Memoization is not a requirement, but reuse of subproblem results is. This may be done top-down (memoization) or bottom-up, but if it's not done, what you have is not dynamic programming at all.

Comment: Im pretty sure its just avoiding recalculating subproblems, which as you rightly pointed out is not the case in this subproblem implementation. (that said im fairly confident there are ways of implementing this problem without having any recalculations...)

Comment: The answer has been completely modified. Now the followup comments don't make any sense. Should have left the original answer and added a separate Update section..